# Add Two Matrix From A Text File (Python w/o Modules)

Tags: python, file, matrix, addition

I am trying to add two matrices from a text file that contains this:

```
[[0,1,2],[9,8,7]] [[6,5,4],[3,4,5]]
```

I have this code:

```
def addition(filename):
a=[]
b=[]
with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().split()
    a=data[0].split()
    b=data[1].split()
a=a[0]
b=b[0]
print (a)
sum = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    print (i)
    c = []
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
        c.append(a[i][j]+b[i][j])
    sum.append(c)
return sum
```

But it outputs:

```
[['[['], ['[['], ['06'], [',,'], ['15'], [',,'], ['24'], [']]'], 
[',,'], ['[['], ['93'], [',,'], ['84'], [',,'], ['75'], [']]'], [']]']]
```

Instead of:

```
[[6,6,6],[12,12,12]]
```

Any idea how I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have `a` and `b` as `strings` - at *no* point do you covert them to `lists`.

You can see this from the result, each `element` is a `concatenation` of the `characters` at each `position` in the `strings`, not the `sum` of just the `elements` (`numbers`).

---

So, to fix this, we just need to covert `a` and `b` to `lists`. If you are sure that the contents of the `file` will always be *just* `lists` (and not accessible to someone else as they could write something malicious), you can use `eval()` for this.

To give a demonstration of how this works:

```
>>> eval("[[0, 1, 2], [9, 8, 7]]")
[[0, 1, 2], [9, 8, 7]]
```

However, if you can't absolutely trust the contents of the `file`, you should use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[[0, 1, 2], [9, 8, 7]]")
[[0, 1, 2], [9, 8, 7]]
```

---

Hopefully, you are capable of applying this to your `code`, and as I don't have access to the `file`, I can't really do this for you.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH @Joe Iddon! This helped a lot!

Comment: @FatCat No problem **:)**